# IntelliJ Idea 11: Updating Classical Application on Frame deactivation

Tags: intellij-idea, embedded-tomcat-7

I am using IntelliJ Idea with 11 Embedded Tomcat - the problem is that there is no settings for "Update classes on Frame deactivation" as it is not typical "Tomcat application". Is there a way to force Idea to show this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for the Application configuration and/or Embedded servers.